# Python: Setting channel values nan where mask > threshold

Tags: python, numpy, mask

probably there is quite an easy solution (without looping around), I am searching for the fastest way possible to:

Set all channels of an rgb image in a stack of images of shape (10, 2160, 4096, 3) to nan if a value in one channel of a stack of mask images of the same shape exceeds a certain threshold t.

```
for i in range(np.shape(stack)[0]):
    stack[mask[i,:,:,:] > t] = np.nan
```

This obviously does no do the job yet as it would only set the values in the same channel to nan. Any help on how to do this? And how to do it as fast as possible (maybe I do not even have to loop over the images in the stack?)
Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Is the channel represented along first or last axis?

Comment: Last axis, it's rgb (the three in the shape tuple)

Comment: Then, simply use `a[a[...,channelID]>t] = np.nan`, where `a` is the image?

Comment: if a threshold in channel 2 of the mask of img 3 (=mask[2,:,:,1]>t) is surpassed, I want stack[2,:,:,:]=np.nan, i.e. np.nan = stack[2,:,:,0] =stack[2,:,:,1] = stack[2,:,:,2]
So it's different, right? yours is basically my example without using the mask?

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone stumbling across this, my solution in the end is:

```
stack[np.nansum(mask > t, axis=-1)>0 ,:] = np.nan
```

(mask > t, axis=-1) gives me a binary array of size three depending on the condition, then I sum this up and if only one of the values is above one (higher than threshold), the >0 is fulfilled, too. I add the channel dimension again and have my condition arraywhich I evaluate for "stack".

I also needed something with three different thresholds and an upper and lower bound for all three channels, just for completion I will add this here:

```
th1=[tl1,tl2,tl3]
th2=[tu1,tu2,tu3]
stack[((mask < th2).any(axis=-1) | (mask > th1).any(axis=-1)), :] = np.nan
```

Cheers!